# Is code first EF known to get unusable with a DbContext containing high number of DbSet?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm hoping for a quick bit of advice just to tell me weather I should suspect (a) I've done something wrong or (b) I am trying to do something that is unsupported.

I generated the code for an `DbContext` with tables from QuickBooks.  It has many tables that I'll never use but I figured it wouldn't hurt.

Everything was going fine until I tried to call `SaveChanges()` after a single insert on the Customer table.  My test case succeeded but he runtime was between 1 and 2 minutes.

Then I removed all but the Customer table and two related tables and the same test succeeded in 2ms.

I'm surprised something as prime time as the entity framework wouldn't handle hundreds of tables in a context, so I figure I am probably doing something wrong.  If this isn't the case I just want to know about it.  I'm not complaining - I don't actually need that many.

One thought I had that might make what I'm doing outside of the normal scenario is that I added all the tables in one giant migration.  Do those binary migration objects get referenced at runtime maybe?

Here's the full code of the DbContext I'm referring to: https://gist.github.com/4677208

Comment: Please show the test code.

Comment: If you have an existing database you would be better off using EF's database first tools.  Code first is for building a database from your code - not using an existing database.

Comment: I understand - the existing database is ODBC, which is also slow and can only be accessed on the same machine that Desktop QuickBooks is running.  I generated this DbContext from the schema of it.  I'm going to post my test code when  I get some time later today though.  I'll also look into the database first way as you suggest, given that I have the tables now...

Answer (score 0):

Was there any database before the first run?

I assume, that calling SaveChanges() first time your database is generated and it might take some time if there are lots of tables and/or some complex logic or much data transfers on initialization in your Seed method or elsewhere.

So, most likely it takes much time not just to insert a single Customer, but to generate whole thing.

Try adding another customer after your committed the first one and see how much time would it take.